# How to convert a string Date to long millseconds

Tags: java, android, epoch, milliseconds, date-conversion

I have a date inside a string, something like "12-December-2012".
How can I convert this into milliseconds (long)?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Using [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String string_date = "12-December-2012";

SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
try {
    Date d = f.parse(string_date);
    long milliseconds = d.getTime();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 20):

It’s about time someone provides the modern answer to this question. In 2012 when the question was asked, the answers also posted back then were good answers. Why the answers posted in 2016 also use the then long outdated classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` is a bit more of a mystery to me. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API also known as JSR-310, is so much nicer to work with. You can use it on Android through the ThreeTenABP, see [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

For most purposes I recommend using the milliseconds since the epoch at the start of the day *in UTC*. To obtain these:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMMM-uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String stringDate = "12-December-2012";
    long millisecondsSinceEpoch = LocalDate.parse(stringDate, dateFormatter)
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toInstant()
            .toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println(millisecondsSinceEpoch);
```

This prints:

```
1355270400000
```

If you require the time at start of day in some specific time zone, specify that time zone instead of UTC, for example:

```
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Asia/Karachi"))
```

As expected this gives a slightly different result:

```
1355252400000
```

Another point to note, remember to supply a locale to your `DateTimeFormatter`. I took December to be English, there are other languages where that month is called the same, so please choose the proper locale yourself. If you didn’t provide a locale, the formatter would use the JVM’s locale setting, which may work in many cases, and then unexpectedly fail one day when you run your app on a device with a different locale setting.

Answer (score 17):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("12-December-2012");
long mills = date.getTime();
```

Answer (score 9):

Take a look to `SimpleDateFormat` class that can parse a `String` and return a `Date` and the `getTime` method of `Date` class.

Answer (score 7):

- First convert string to `java.util.Date` using date [formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- Use [getTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) to obtain count of millisecs from date

Answer (score 3):

you can use the simpleDateFormat to parse the string date.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is used the Date Using Date()  and  getTime()

```
    Date dte=new Date();
    long milliSeconds = dte.getTime();
    String strLong = Long.toString(milliSeconds);
    System.out.println(milliSeconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

using simpledateformat you can easily achieve it.

1) First convert string to java.Date using simpledateformatter.

2) Use getTime method to obtain count of millisecs from date

```
 public class test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      String currentDate = "01-March-2016";
      SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
     Date parseDate = f.parse(currentDate);
     long milliseconds = parseDate.getTime();
  }
        }
```

more Example click [here](https://qamanual.blogspot.in/2016/06/how-to-convert-string-date-into.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("your_string_format", Locale.getDefault());
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = f.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long timeInMillis = d.getTime();
```