# Error in converting Date to String

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, long-integer, date-parsing

```
        Date date = new Date();
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(s);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Timestamp timestamp=new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        id=Long.parseLong(timestamp.toString());
```

On executing the above code I got this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2018-08-29 16:35:31.753"
    at 
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

What's wrong in it now?

Comment: `timestamp.toString()` returns "2018-08-29 16:35:31.753" - you can't use `Long.parseLong` on that. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: As greg-449 says, you're parsing a date string to a long variable, this isn't working as you need to set a long representation in a string variable. If you're trying to get the milliseconds, you need to use `long id = date.getTime(); `

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a string Date to long millseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473550/how-to-convert-a-string-date-to-long-millseconds). Please search, and you will find many more helpful questions and answers.

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse("2018-08-29 16:35:31.753".replace(' ', 'T')).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()`. On my computer it gave (all odd digits) 1 535 553 331 753, but the result depends on the time zone.

Answer (score 2):

The error happens when you try to get long value by `Timestamp.toString()`, since it returns `2018-08-29 16:35:31.753`, which is not a valid long.

Just use:

```
long id = timestamp.getTime();
```