# Converting string to date and using query greater than operator is not working as expected in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am using cassandra 2.2.3 and below is my table structure to store doj as date object.

```
Table structure:

class Emp{

String name
Date doj
}
empdata:

id                  name                          doj
1                   Test                         2010-01-01 00:00:00+0000
2                   Test1                        2011-01-01 00:00:00+0000
```

I have to use greater than or less than operator to select the employees between those dates.

From the json i get the following input to display the data.

```
{
"dateFrom":'1/1/2010'
}
```

//Modified the string to date using SimpleDateFormat

```
Date d1 = f.parse(dateFrom);
long milliseconds = d1.getTime();
```

//Query call to use the gte operator to fetch the data from Cassandra

```
Select selectQuery = QueryBuilder.select().all().from(tableName).allowFiltering()
Where selectWhere = selectQuery.where();
rangeClause(selectWhere,dateFrom,Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2010);
Statement s = selectWhere.limit(1)
println("st is:"+s); 

In the select statement i see the query as "SELECT * FROM emp WHERE doj>=1551427200000  LIMIT 1;


//Function Call

 def rangeClause(Where selectWhere, String columnName, Object columnValue) 
    {
    Clause whereClause = null
    whereClause= QueryBuilder.gte(columnName, columnValue.get("dateFrom"))
    selectWhere.and(whereClause)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`dateFrom` is a timestamp (long) which is 8 bytes and your passing it a String '2010-01-05' thats 10 bytes. You need to convert that date string into a epoc timestamp (long) or Date.

Comment: Can you please tell how to convert String to epoc timestamp?

Comment: parse it into a Date then get the timestamp from it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12473614/266337

Comment: I modified the code as per your link.But still i am not getting the expected result as in the select query i see that it is converting to some string.