# How to convert date in string to Long in java?

Tags: java

I have date and time in string format in one of my models.
`"startTime": "2022-10-19T14:31:22+00:00"`

How can I convert it to long format in Java?

I tried using
`'Long.valueOf(startTime)' and 'Long.parseLong(startTime)'` are two functions.

but in both I am getting an exception.

```
"at the java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)"
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `spring-boot`? How are you receiving/working with `startTime`?

Comment: Hello @Ravi. Next time try to ask the question in Google like you did here. The first result would point you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473550/how-to-convert-a-string-date-to-long-millseconds

Comment: @gfelisberto Actually, [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473550/how-to-convert-a-string-date-to-long-millseconds) is not a good duplicate of this. The [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75355402/642706) on this page is more appropriate, and briefer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse your datetime format using builtin methods - also to convert it to a long value (assuming the number of seconds since the epoch).

```
Instant.parse("2022-10-19T14:31:22+00:00").getEpochSecond()
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html

See code run [at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/apIHUN).

Comment: Interesting. Instant doesn't say that it will parse an offset datetime but it seems it will

Comment: @g00se I too was surprised to find `Instant.parse` worked as well as using `OffsetDateTime.parse`. Worked with `+01:00` too. I vaguely recall this more flexible formatting being tolerated by `Instant.parse` in later versions, after the initial Java 8 release, but I'm not sure.

Comment: From Java SE 15 Javadoc for `Instant#parse()`: _"When parsing, the behaviour of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendOffsetId()` will be used to parse the offset, converting the instant to UTC as necessary."_

Comment: @JimGarrison I don't see that [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Sorry, it's in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`, which is linked from `Instant#parse()`.